How is hydrostatic pressure over a column affected when a barrier is introduced some way down the column?
How is measured hydrostatic pressure of a column of fluid affected by introduction of a barrier at some point within the column.  Per attached diagram you have a 100ft column of fluid with gradient of 0.5psi/ft.  In the initial condition the pressure gauge at the bottom of the column would read 50psi.  Now, if I introduce a sealing barrier at 50ft within the column how would this affect the pressure recorded on the gauge?  Would it still read 50psi (the original pressure is trapped below the barrier), or would it reduce to 25psi (i.e. the new hydrostatic pressure is only affected by the isolated column of fluid below)?


The height and density of the column of fluid add pressure as you descend through the column.
In the column on the left, if we assume it is open on the top, then it will have approximately 1atm pressure at the top.   We can then calculate the additional pressure that the fluid creates on the bottom.
In the column on the right, the bottom section is a completely sealed box.   We have no information about the pressure at the top of that section under the valve.   We can calculate the pressure difference between the top and the bottom of the chamber, but not the absolute values.   You would need to know what the state of the fluid was when you closed the valve.

Thanks for your answer. If we assume 1 atm = 14.5 psi (for simplicity) then the gauge on left would read 64.5 psia. If the right hand column was in exact same condition prior to closure of isolation valve, how would this affect the gauge reading?

Closing the valve doesn't change the pressure.   It just "locks in" the pressure so that changes outside the sealed section no longer matter.
